# Idempotent decomposition (in proof of Serre's criterion for normality)

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of [Serre's criterion for normality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_criterion_for_normality#Sufficiency) (the "sufficiency" part). Let $A$ be commutative Noetherian ring. The proof:

Suppose $A$ satisfies $S_2$ and $R_1$. ($S_i$ and $R_i$ are explaned in the link.) Then $A$ in particular satisfies $S_1$ and $R_0$; hence, it is reduced. If $\mathfrak {p}_{i},\,1\leq i\leq r$ are the minimal prime ideals of $A$, then the total ring of fractions $K$ of $A$ is the direct product of the residue fields $ \kappa ({\mathfrak {p}}_{i})=Q(A/{\mathfrak {p}}_{i})$: see total ring of fractions of a reduced ring. That means we can write $ 1=e_{1}+\dots +e_{r}$ where $ e_{i}$ are idempotents in $ \kappa ({\mathfrak {p}}_{i})$ and such that $e_{i}e_{j}=0,\,i\neq j$...

*Question:* Last claim I do not understand. Why we can find *idempotent* $e_i \in  \kappa ({\mathfrak {p}}_{i})$ satisfying $ 1=e_{1}+\dots +e_{r}$? Due to direct product decomposition of $K$ we can find $f_i\in \kappa ({\mathfrak {p}}_{i})$ with  $ 1=f_{1}+\dots +f_{r}$. But why these $f_i$ can moreover be chosen to be *idempotents*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$K\simeq \kappa(p_1)\times\cdots\times \kappa(p_r)$$

as rings where the multiplication on the ring on the right is componentwise.

Let $e_i\in K$ such that under the above isomorphism $e_i$ corresponds to $(0, 0,\dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)$ where $i^{th}$ co-ordinate is 1 and the rest is 0.

Now you can check the 'idempotent condition for $e_i $'s.